# Is there a way to include a SpriteKit scene in a SceneKit Scene?

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

I am wondering if it is possible to include a SpriteKit scene in a SceneKit scene, and if it is, how to do that ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the Sprite Kit scene in the Scene Kit scene?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist For example, I would have a 3D node of a television and my SpriteKit scene would be the screen of the TV, so it would be on a plane node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is!

You can assign a Sprite Kit scene (`SKScene`) as the `contents` of a material property (`SCNMaterialProperty`) in Scene Kit.

Comment: You can also use a SpriteKit `SKScene` as an [overlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/overlaySKScene) overlay on an entire SceneKit scene. And you can put SceneKit content into a SpriteKit scene with [`SK3DNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SK3DNode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014196). I haven't tried to see how many levels of SceneKit-in-SpriteKit-in-SceneKit-etc you can get up to, though. :)

Comment: It works, but my SKScene isn't played on the SCNGeometry object. I just see static texture without animation. Should it play?

Comment: @RuslanK - It it's not playing, check the SKScene.isPaused is set to false

Answer (score 3):

I've come across a few questions about this exact topic and there don't seem to be a whole lot of actual code examples, so here's another one. Hopefully this is helpful:

```
SKSpriteNode *someSKSpriteNode;

// initialize your SKSpriteNode and set it up..

SKScene *tvSKScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
tvSKScene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[tvSKScene addChild:someSKSpriteNode];

// use spritekit scene as plane's material

SCNMaterial *materialProperty = [SCNMaterial material];
materialProperty.diffuse.contents = tvSKScene;

// this will likely change to whereever you want to show this scene.
SCNVector3 tvLocationCoordinates = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);

SCNPlane *scnPlane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:100.0 height:100.0];
SCNNode *scnNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:scnPlane];
scnNode.geometry.firstMaterial = materialProperty;
scnNode.position = tvLocationCoordinates;

// Assume we have a SCNCamera and SCNNode set up already.

SCNLookAtConstraint *constraint = [SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:cameraNode];
constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = NO;
scnNode.constraints = @[constraint];

// Assume we have a SCNView *sceneView set up already.
[sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:scnNode];
```